# Can I use WebView inside a View (react native)?

Tags: webview, react-native

I am trying to use WebView Component inside View component, for a react native application I am working on. When I embed WebView inside View, I am not seeing the content I am displaying in WebView. Is this the expected behavior with react native?

Comment: Normally the WebView should appear. Try setting flex to 1 for both the View and the WebView or setting explicit sizes.

Comment: could you place your sample code at rnplay.org?

Comment: It should work. Set all your parent Views and your Webview to flex:1

Comment: Thank you all! I tried the flex: 1 approach. It worked!

Comment: Perhaps Nico or @abeikverdi should post your comments as answers, so user4122421 can accept it.

Comment: I added the answer. I think that should solve the OP problem.

Answer (score 30):

You should specify a width and height for your webview.
Do it as follow:

```
render() {
return (
  <WebView
    source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
    style={{flex: 1}} // OR style={{height: 100, width: 100}}
  />
);}
```

Answer (score 29):

When it's nested inside a View component, you need to set both view and webview flex to 1.

eg. -

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: url }}
      style={{flex:1}}
      />
</View>
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Why?

Comment: My 5 cents. I've been trying to use for the View a general style for containers in my app. But my container style includes `alignItems` attribute which as I understood doesn't fit with WebViews. When I switched to a simple style just with `flex: 1` the WebView appeared.

Comment: @DarthEgregious Don't know the exact reason behind it, however, this is a restriction with the webview due to which it needs a view having flex 1.

Comment: @VladimirVlasov Yes. That happens. WebView generally has a lot of restrictions with regard to attributes.

Answer (score 7):

Please use following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, ImageBackground, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class WebViewScreen extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <WebView 
                    source= {{uri: 'https://www.google.com'}}
                    style= {styles.loginWebView}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'stretch',
    },
    loginWebView: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 30,
        marginBottom: 20
    }
});
```

this code is working absolutely fine for me,

In all above solutions I observed that everyone is suggesting to add **flex: 1** to your webView style.

Yes it is correct but in case you want to nest WebView inside View then **you need to specify styles of your parent view precisely.**

So, I set **justifyContent: 'flex-start'** so that vertically WebView will start from top of my screen and **alignItems: 'stretch'** so that WebView will take all available in horizontal direction

**As we use justifyContent to specify primary axis alignment and alignItems to specify secondary axis alignment and default flexDirection is column.**

To get more information on how to install react-native-webview please refer following link:
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started.md

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it?

Answer (score 2):

For **WebView** in **View**, We can use this code for **.js** and **.tsx** files in **React-native**.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class WebViewExample extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <View style={{height:"100%" , width:"100%"}}>
     <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/' }}/>
   </View>
   );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use something like this

```
render() {
let {url} = this.props.webDetail;

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {this.renderSpinner()}
    <WebView onLoad={this.onWebLoad.bind(this)}
      source={{ uri: url }}
      scalesPageToFit={true}
      />
  </View>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to open a pdf file.
Li'l out of the box but I am sure it would help someone :)

```
{
    Platform.OS === "android" ? 
        <WebView  
            source={{uri:'http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=https://your PDF Link'}}
            style={{flex: 1}}
        />
        :
        <WebView
            source={{uri:'https:your PDF Link'}}
            style={{flex: 1}}
        />
}
```